# AH01909: RSA certificate configured for subdomain.subdomain.domain.co.uk:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Tags: ssl, bitbucket

I'm having trouble automating a push from Bitbucket to my server and when I check the server log files I see the following error:

> AH01909: RSA certificate configured for *subdomain.subdomain.domain.co.uk:443* does NOT include an ID which
>   matches the server name.

When I view the Bitbucket Webhook requests I get timeout errors.

I've also tried turning SSL on and off.

I feel like I've exhausted all avenues trying to get this to work, can somebody give some advice on what I need to do or at least debug?

Here's the certificate used on the subdomain:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Post the SSL certificate in your question.

Comment: Or the domain, so we can pull the cert. It basically sounds like you don't have a wildcard cert, and also don't have a suitable CN or SAN (SubjectAlternativeName) for your sub-sub-domain.

Comment: I'm using letsencrypt.org for my certificate. It's installed automatically through Plesk. Apparently they do not offer Wildcard certificates (https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/can-i-use-letsencrypt-in-more-than-one-subdomain/16588). Do I need a wildcard certificate for it to work?

Comment: i've added the certificate to the post.

Comment: This cert only has one name, `dev.san***.tsa***.co.uk`. You need to generate the certificate with every server name in the virtual host in one go.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean every subdomain in one certificate? Can you do that with Lets Encrypt?